# monitor tp4056 charge current on a scope

Tags: current, oscilloscope, monitor

I assembled a li-on charger with the TP4056 module as I've repaired a few solar lights for friends and a lot of the times the batteries are just low.

Recently I purchased an Oscilloscope to use with other projects. I would like to monitor the charge current on my scope but am having difficulty finding the correct pin.

I recently found an, "older," youtube video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfrm6lbt8Pc&t=626s" on this but he uses an older module which I believe doesn't have the protection circuits that mine has.

Am including the video link as it may assist other along with a link showing my tp4056, "https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjZLOy6GbYksgdJBMVos5ID12jcBsQ." The input solder joint was fixed after I saw the image enlarged. TIA, Steven

Comment: Hi, Steve, and welcome to EE.SE. There aren't many of us going to watch three videos for you. If you want your question read by many then put enough information into your question. This should include the datasheet link for the TP4056, maybe some video screengrabs and, of course, a schematic.

Comment: There isn’t one. You need to provide a shunt resistor in series or some other means of measuring the current. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the value and location of your R3, it is Rprog, programmed for 1A.

below it is called R4 and 122 = 1.2k = Rprog @ 1A
[image]
[image]

https://circuit-diagramz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/TP4056-Datasheet.pdf